# In django, login page content is not displaying only navbar is visible

Tags: python, django, django-views

Screenshots:
[Login Page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhUd3.png)

[Login Page html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTPPV.png)

[Project level url file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEDoE.png)

[base.html page which contains the login link in navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3ez3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
{% block content_block %}
```

in the login template, while the block in the base template is

```
{% block content %}
```

Change the login template to use `{% block content %}`.

Also, next time don't post screenshots of code.